# Multi-node cassandra cluster: OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection (5 seconds)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

After firing some async queries  on my multi node cluster using a python program , one of my node in cluster has gone down.

> cassandra.pool:Error attempting to reconnect to 192.168.19.5,
>   scheduling retry in 4.0 seconds: errors=Timed out creating connection
>   (5 seconds), last_host=None

But upon `nodetool status`, I see all of my nodes to be up. 
I tried cqlsh on the affected node but received the following error:

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers',
>   {'': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating
>   connection (5 seconds), last_host=None',)})

I am wondering whether if it is a client request timeout or connect timeout or server-side read request timeout.

To resolve the issue: I tried `cqlsh <affected_node_ip> --request-timeout 20` but I am still getting the same Connection error.

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by:

1. Navigated to the `~/.cassandra` directory
2. Since the cqlshrc file was absent, I copied the `cqlshrc.sample` from conf folder of cassandra
3. Renamed it to `cqlshrc`
4. Updated cqlshrc file with: [connection]
   timeout = 3600
5. restarted cluster

Answer (score 0):

Use `--connect-timeout=`

Command:
`cqlsh <affected_node_ip> --connect-timeout=20`

Here you can pass the connection timeout string.

```
request-timeout: for cassandra db request
```